# Cannot Access Resources (like Local Storage) when Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

When I inspect WebViews or Chrome tabs as described here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

I cannot access anything in the 'Resources' tab in the dev tools. For example, when I click on something in Local Storage, nothing happens (see picture). Since my search did not turn up anything, is this just generally not possible? If it's not possible for Chrome for Android tabs, can I maybe enable access to these Resources in my WebView?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer to this? I've tried as per https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap and getting same issue as you. Other tabs such as console and network are working.

Comment: unfortunately not. you can get around this by `adb shell`'ing into the device and get access to your local storage that way, but it's rather cumbersome.

Comment: Hi, I also see the same issue in iOS/Safari. I assume because of your question, you are using Cordova? If so, you can use the new(ish) "browser" platform which runs in Chrome, and you can inspect/edit local sstorage there, while developing. If you need forther details let me know

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Did not have this to hand yesterday http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/9/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps